# Сделать кнопку неактивной после нажатия

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица. Есть кнопка *add*, которая по нажатию добавляет новую строку к таблице. Хочу сделать так, чтобы кнопка была активна только 1 раз. Или может ее можно как-то скрыть?

```
$('.add').click(function(){добавление строки по нажатию}
```

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://jquery-docs.ru/one/

Comment: $('.add').click(function(){$(this).hide()});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#two').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true); // Либо добавить атрибут disabled 
  });

  $('#one').click(function() {
    $(this).hide(); // Либо скрыть
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="one">Скрыть</button>
<button id="two">Добавить атрибут disabled</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.add').click(function(){
// код добавления и всякие там манипуляции 

  $(this).remove() - удалить
  // или
  $(this).hide() - скрыть
  // или
  $(this).attr('disabled', true); - неактивная (если button, или input submit)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.add').css("display", "none");
```

В функцию клика, если все-таки надо скрыть.

```
$(".add").attr('disabled',true);
```

Если сделать неактивной.